# Misrepresented as making a post community wiki

Tags: bug, community-wiki

Mi answer is labeled as [been made a community wiki by me](https://academia.stackexchange.com/posts/110003/revisions).

> Post Made Community Wiki by Jose Antonio Dura Olmos

That is not the case, I did not make the answer community wiki.

There may be good reasons for a moderator or automatic script to have done so. That's fine if so. But, please, don't attribute such action to me.

Comment: Please see [this](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/109937/how-can-i-avoid-being-intolerant-and-unsupportive-of-diversity-at-scientific-mee/110003#comment288077_109937)

Comment: @Wrzlprmft I see that. I'm fine with it being turned automatically into a community wiki. I'm not fine with such automatic action being attributed to me. Though... if this issue is not specific to Academia I should raise it in StackExchange meta rather than here.

Comment: Yeah, that's a SE systemwide "feature."

Answer (score 2):

Your answer was automatically marked as Community Wiki because you answered a Community Wiki question. See *How does a post become a Community Wiki post?* in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/11741/300001).

Comment: Since you say it was *automatically* marked I assume you agree the one marking it was not me. Since I wrote the post *manually*.

Comment: @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos If you're answering a Community Wiki post you're accepting that your answer will be marked Community Wiki by the system _on your behalf_, because this is the behaviour implemented by SE. If you want a different behaviour, you should make the proposal on the [main Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/). Don't expect your proposal to be accepted, though.